# Create Dynamic Text with new lines

Tags: r, string, dynamic

I am trying to create a text box for displaying text in `ggplot2`. For stylizing the text, I want the information to be split between several lines. This is what I am trying:

```
txt1<-paste("Question: ", df$q1) ; txt2<-paste("Gender: ", df$gender)
txt3<-paste("response: ", df$rspns)
txt<-cat(paste(txt1, txt2, txt3, sep = "\n"))
```

When I try to print `txt` it is shown as `NULL` because the output of `cat` does not get assigned to `txt`. I have tried using `capture.output(cat(paste(txt1, txt2, txt3, sep = "\n")))` but that breaks the lines to different entries in a list.

There does not seem to be a simple solution to create dynamic multi-line text in R. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: Remove the `cat(...)` wrapping around the data - just `paste(txt1, txt2, txt3, sep = "\n")` will do it. `cat` is used for output to the screen or a file, not for saving to an object as you have found.

Comment: @thelatemail: I have tried that. It produces  `Question: Q3\nGender: Female\nresponse:  743`

Comment: Yep, which is your information split across multiple lines - `\n` is a line break. If you do `cat(paste(txt1, txt2, txt3, sep = "\n"))` you will see how the text will be printed on your graph. Try `plot(1); text(1,1,paste(txt1, txt2, txt3, sep = "\n"))` for some proof.

Comment: @thelatemail: Yes. That is working when I pass `txt` to ggplot. Can you add this as an answer with some explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue here is that `cat` is used for displaying text on the screen or outputting to a text file (or other connection). When trying to save the output of `cat` like:

```
out <- cat("blah")
```

nothing is returned to be assigned to out. As per the help file at `?cat`:

> Value:
>
> None (invisible ‘NULL’).

`paste` is appropriate to use to join strings together, including with line breaks (represented by `\n` when shown on the command line in R).

```
x <- "line one"
y <- "line two"

paste(x,y,sep="\n")
#[1] "line one\nline two"
```

While this doesn't look like it is supposed to on the command line, and appears all on one line, it is actually what you want. You can in fact use `cat` again to check how the formatted output will look on your graph in the end:

```
cat(paste(x,y,sep="\n"))
#line one
#line two
```